# Inverse of a log - mooculus question

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I'm trying to solve this question from mooculus and I get the wrong answer:
[image]

What I did:

$d=10\cdot \log_{10}(\frac I{I_0}) \\
 \frac d{10} = \log_{10}(\frac I{I_0})\\
10^\frac d{10}=\frac I{I_0}\\
I_0\cdot 10^\frac d{10} = I
$

But then $ d^{-1}(85) = 10^{8.5} \cdot I_0 $
But the the answer is :

$ d^{-1}(85) = 3.2 \cdot 10^8 $
 or approximately 320 million
times the threshold sound.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong -- $10^{8.5}$ *is* approximately $3.2\times 10^8$, because $10^{0.5}=\sqrt{10} \approx 3.2$.

(The model answer is missing the $I_0$ factor from the result, which must be a typo).

Comment: Thank you I feel Like a moron for not seeing this.